# Plyer Notification Type Error

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

I'm trying to figure out how plyer notifications work and found a simple example, however it doesn't work for me. I get a type error.

```
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'ticker'
```

Here's the code:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from plyer import notification

class Notif(FloatLayout):
    def notify(self):
        notification.notify(title='title', message='m', ticker='r')

class MainApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Notif()


MainApp().run()
```

and the kv part

```
<Notif>:
    Button:
        text: "Notify"
        on_release: root.notify()
```

Of course I tried to just delete the "ticker" argument but I got the same error even with no "ticker" specified.

Comment: I can't reproduce it in Linux (Python 3.6.3/Plyer 1.3.0). Do you use Windows? See https://github.com/kivy/plyer/issues/333

Comment: Yes I use windows. But the suggestion by KeyWeeUsr didn't seem to fix my issue. I copied his code and it still didn't work at all

Comment: You can install the 1.3.1 dev0 version directly from GitHub, do: `pip install -I https://github.com/kivy/plyer/zipball/master`. It isn't a stable version of plyer but it has the bug fixed (https://github.com/kivy/plyer/commit/0007a63f9571be54dfeeeb2830faa2162e0ef99f)